# Is it possible to reuse a form but gets a different result?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Is it possible to reuse a form so that I don't need to create a different one? Let's say i have a fill up form1, when I click on submit, all the text input from that form1 will be recorded into a datagridview1. Is there any way I can use that same form1 so that when I click on a different button, all the text input from the same form1 gets recorded into a different datagridview?
Highly appreciated!

Edit: 
Here is a code that I want to achieve. I'll make it as simple as possible.

```
'This is form1. I want this form to ask form2 to send data to form3 
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles 
Button1.Click
form3.Datagridview.Rows.Add("form2.textbox1.text", "form2.textbox2.text")
form3.Show()
Me.Hide()
End Sub
```

Now here I want to use a different form, let's call it form1v1. I want this form to ask the same form2 to send a different data to form4 without trigerring the above code. How am I going to approach that?'

The only possible method I can think of is using if statements like

```
If buttonclickedonform1 then
    send data to form3
else if buttonclickedonform1v1 then
    send data to form 4
```

But is there even such thing?
Thank you!

Comment: Yes it's possible.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Its really important to ask questions properly here. Have a look at [ask] and [mcve]. As it stands, your question is off-topic. This site is for questions regarding specific issues with existing code. Dont let negative votes or votes to close put you off though. Thanks

Comment: Very easy in window form. But you should include some details or code then we can help you. Otherwise it is easy.

Comment: @DavidWilson I apologize for asking improperly. I have edited my question now.

Comment: @Abhiverma I have edited my question and included a code. Please take a look. Thank you.

Comment: @Babbillumpa how do I approach it?

Comment: As the tags explain. vba is not the same as VB.NET.  Please fix those as well

Comment: Can you explain this, Sorry bro I don't understand this line **I want this form to ask form2 to send data to form3**.